# Select2 not opening after first selection on text field

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using jquery select2 plugin to display a list of `<li>` items, but on an input text field instead of `<select>`. here is my html:

```
<div class="item-holder">
    <input type="hidden" name="item" id="item" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name" placeholder="Select Item" autocomplete="off"/>
    <ul class="item-list">
        <ul class="item-list list">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2 </li>
            <li>item 3 </li>
            <li>item 4 </li>                                
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my code is this:

```
$('#item_name').select2({ width: '185px', placeholder: "Select Item", allowClear : true});

$("#item_name").on('click', function(e) {
    $(".item-list").toggle();
});

var options = {
    valueNames : [ 'item_name' ]
};

var brand_List = new List('item_holder', options);
```

Up to this stage everything works fine and smooth. When I select an item from the list, clear selection with keyboard, and want to select another option from the list, the list doesn't appear. seems like `select2` list doesn't appear for second time. Neither can I see 'clear' button if I enable `allowClear : true` option. Whats going wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you open developer tools and run through your steps do you see an error in the console?

Comment: Hi @Noctane Thanks for the comment. I do not see any error in console.

Comment: Why do you hide the items from the dropdown on the click event of the input field ?

Comment: @Zafar DinoMyte has a good point, your select wont open if there is nothing in the select, when you use `$(".item-list").toggle();` you are basically hiding the options in your select, toggle will toggle them from show to hide, and back. [See Toggle API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Hi @DinoMyte its because after a selection has been made, there is no point in showing the entire list. Its same like a datepicker plugin, once you select a date, there is no need to show the whole calendar. So in your view, what should be the solution?

Comment: But even toggle() is not working as intended. It should hide list on first selection, and it should open the list on second selection, right? But it doesn't. It only shows for the first time @Noctane

Comment: @Zafar is there anyway you could prepare a demo using jsfiddle or codebin so I can take a look? you may want to comment the toggle out and see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are basically building the options for the select2 from the dropdown menu. In such case, you can create an array from the list options and then get rid of the dropdown itself.

```
var arr = []; 
$(".item-list.list li").each(function(i)
{
  var obj = {
    id: i,
    text: $(this).text()
  };
   arr.push(obj);
});

$('ul.item-list').remove();

$('#item_name').select2({
    width: '185px',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    autocomplete: 'off',
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    placeholder: "Select Item",    
    data: arr  
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/fyhsz9ra/427/

Comment: Hi @DinoMyte it worked. Thumbs Up! Thank you so much for this. However, I would like this input text box to stay as an input box instead of appearing like a drop down. How could we achieve this desired result?

Comment: Sure. Glad to help. Select2 basically creates a dynamic ul object with class='select2-results' when you interact with the select2 field. This is how the API works. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Hi @DinoMyte  Thanks for further explanation. However, I have trouble accessing data attributes of this array. Since this is neither an option list nor a list that we created, how do I access its attributes? say id and name? Just wondering.

Comment: extract the select2 data using .select2('data') . Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/fyhsz9ra/428/